# How does Instagram customize the UIKeyboard returnKey to an '@' and a '#"?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikeyboard, instagram

The most recent version of the Instagram iOS app does something interesting. When writing in a text field (e.g., posting a comment), the UIKeyboard's return key has been replaced by two keys: an `@` key and a `#` key. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Instagram keyboard]

I would like to know how they do this. As far as I can tell, `@` and `#` keys behave like normal keys: they disappear in keyboards that do not usually have returnKey (such as the emoji keyboard), etc.

The only thing that occurs to me as of now is that the app is getting a reference to the `UIKeyboard` and looping through the subviews, finding and hiding the `returnKey`, then finding and moving the `@` and `#` keys. Any other ideas?

Comment: "Moving" keys is not so easy - most keys are part of a single keyboard image, presumably for performance reasons (the "pressed" overlay is significantly larger than the key images to prevent edge artifacts, e.g. with the drop shadow). It is more likely that the keys are added as separate views. Try running the app with the "Color blended layers" CoreAnimation instrument turned on.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That seems to be a text field whose [`keyboardType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/keyboardType) is set to `UIKeyboardTypeTwitter`, first introduced in iOS 5. It's exactly the same keyboard layout that is used by Tweet Sheets in iOS 5, with the return key being replaced by the `@` and `#` keys respectively.

Since Instagram happens to use `@` for referring to users and `#` for tagging posts, just like Twitter, I'm guessing that they're borrowing `UIKeyboardTypeTwitter` for convenient use with their own app.